# A superlative form of right

Tags: superlatives

Is it possible to derive a superlative form of right (meaning **the opposite of left**) - the rightest?

Answer (score 43):

Rightmost would fit here.

Incidentally, leftmost for left.

Not quite one word, but you could use 'farthest to the right' or 'farthest to the left' as the case may be.

FUN FACT:

When you use 'Right' as in correct, the superlative form becomes 'Most right'. English, right?!

Comment: the rightmost answer is the most right in this case.

Comment: Another fun fact, in very many languages, the word for "right" as the direction is also the word for "correctness" or "law" - and the word for left is usually the same as "wrong" or "opposite" or "strange". Hard to be a lefty.

Comment: @StianYttervik Something sinister is going on there

Comment: @Sabre - Don't be gauche.

Comment: This was a most dexterous answer! Quite adroit!

Comment: [Technically correct.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo)

Comment: This seems to be the correctmost answer.